# Functionality of IJWNOADThunkJumpTarget

Tags: c#

When I invoked a manged C++ call from a C++ DCOM server I got the following callstack. The manged C++ call sets a property value.

**My question is what does IJWNOADThunkJumpTarget, IJWNOADThunkJumpTargetHelper and IJWNOADThunk::FindThunkTarget do?**

Please help me

```
mscorwks!SetupThread+00000238
 mscorwks!IJWNOADThunk::FindThunkTarget+00000019
 mscorwks!IJWNOADThunkJumpTargetHelper+0000000B
 mscorwks!IJWNOADThunkJumpTarget+00000048
 ICEScheduler!CToolDataManager::SetLotManagerActive+00000025** (e:\projects\ice\ice_dev\trunk\source\application source\iceschedulersystem\icescheduler\tooldatamanager.cpp, 250)
 ICEScheduler!SetLotManagerActive+00000014 (e:\projects\ice\ice_dev\trunk\source\application source\iceschedulersystem\icescheduler\schddllapi.cpp, 589)
```

Comment: Does it look like it's causing problems, or are you asking out of curiosity?

Comment: I got a memory leak.. I am trying to fix the memory leak.. The details can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473818/managed-c-memory-leak

Comment: Bah, not linking that in your question was criminal.

Comment: I am sorry Hans.. But How can I link?

Comment: You managed to put a link in the comment, I'm sure you can figure it out.  Voting to close as dup.

Answer (score 3):

- It's part of the .NET runtime internals (i.e. it's not a public API)
- It's not included in the SSCLI source code (for instance, see the comment in [*dacvars.h*](http://www.koders.com/c/fidAFA2E2158A71B68BAC2FE61FCC40650A7AAEA895.aspx?s=IJWNOADThunk#L55)); it's only in the Microsoft .NET Framework
- The 'IJW' part of the name suggests that it's some plumbing used only by managed C++ (IJW = 'It Just Works', and refers to MC++'s ability to mix native and managed code)
- The 'thunk' part of the name suggests that it's a piece of helper code responsible for gluing together two other pieces of code
- Other mentions of `IJWOADThunk` on the web ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150205043624/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/06/17/badimageformatexception-or-typeinitializationexception-when-using-mixed-mode-vc-dlls-in-managed-services-applications.aspx), [here](https://tech-archive.net/)) are in contexts where managed code calls into native code or vice versa

Given the above, I would guess that the `IJWOADThunk` functions are what allows your managed C++ code to interoperate transparently with native code.

Comment: I got a memory leak.. I am trying to fix the memory leak.. The details can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473818/managed-c-memory-leak